# Can't connect to MySQL, even though running

Tags: php, mysql, terminal, connection

This is driving me crazy! I have MySQL preference pane on my Mac OS X Lion, and also start and stop it from Terminal. mysql works from terminal and I can connect to databases, but when I do it from PHP source code it doesn't connect. It worked last night but now it doesn't and I dont know why. Here is a few details:

- I'm telling `php.ini` to look for mysql.sock in the correct directory
- I have also set the `socket` variable in `my.cnf` of mysql to the correct path.
- Just to be sure, I have created a symlink in the default directory for mysql socket (`/tmp/mysql.sock`) to link to the socket file in `/var/tmp/mysql.sock`.
- When I have stopped MySQL from the preference pane, and I try to start it from Terminal, it says 'SUCCESS!' but I can't use it with the command `mysql` in Terminal.

Can anyone get anything out from this messed up situation??

Comment: Voting to migrate to [su]; but does the user under which terminal is running have write access to `/var/tmp/mysql.sock`?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the MySQL server via PHP?

Comment: @JamesElliott No I can't connect via PHP.

Comment: it says `srwxrwxrwx` in the access part of the socket file, so it should do @eggyal

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I was getting `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)` when I couldn't connect from the terminal. But I just restarted and it's working now! I had tried restarting before but no hope.

Comment: I think using the MySQL pref pane and the terminal commands together screws something up in the configuration or something

Comment: @eggyal please check the answer below and let me know if you have something that I don't understand. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question:**

OK so I don't know why but I had discrepancies in the configuration. Even though I had set the `socket` variable in my.cnf file, when I started mysql server, it always looked for a different location for the socket.

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/tmp/mysql.sock

[client]
socket=/var/tmp/mysql.sock
```

and I was still getting the error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`. Note how it still looks for `/tmp/mysql.sock`?

After finding this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/rainy/entry/why_isn_t_mysql_using), I realised that my mysql server was never reading my config file in `/usr/local/mysql/my.cnf`.

This is what I got from `mysqladmin` command:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

**Solution:**  I created a symlink in my home folder

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

And yess! Problem solved :)

Comment: What is the location of that `my.cnf`?

Comment: it's in `/usr/local/mysql/`, its default directory when I installed it. I haven't changed it. But I have also searched other directories for a different `my.cnf` with no result. So I assumed that was the only one that mysql checked?

Comment: This is what I get from running `mysqladmin | more`: `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf` Since I don't have a `my.cnf` file in my home dir, the one I've set variables in is definitely read the last. So strange

Comment: wouw wouw wait! I spotted something. It's never reading my config file?

Comment: Depends on the `MYSQL_HOME` environment variable.